# Can I test android system apps on a normal un-rooted phone?

Tags: android

I am developing app which will come pre-installed with certain devices, however im testing the app on my own device and will need to demo it on my own device. At the moment its fine as im testing it as a user app, but now i need to use permissions which only the system apps get to use. Is their a way in the project settings to say its a system app so I can test and demo it?

Comment: I'm not sure how the permissions differ, but this is a list of the permissions you can place in your manifest: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: I need to use "CALL_PRIVILEGED". However if you try and add it to the manifest it does not compile as it says. "This permission is only granted to system apps".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short answer - i would root your phone. However, unlocking the bootloader is possible without root. So, IMO,  you could install CWM as your recovery, then boot to CWM, then use the CWM option to MOUNT system, then use adb to copy your .apk to /cache, then use linux util 'cat' to get the apk from /cache to /system/app, then unmount /system using CWM, then reboot.

long answer - if you are developing system apps, learn the security environment of android. Learn the issues around permissions in the /system folder, and learn the recovery type tools that allow a developer to have access to the /system folder where adb activities like install , uninstall are restricted.

[This](http://snipplr.com/view/51901/android-emulator--replace-system-app/) is an older discussion 'froyo' on how-to install system app, illustrating some of the permissions issues in the /system folder. I would not simply follow these instructions without reading up on how its done in honeycomb and in ICS.

Comment: I'll accept that as the answer, through I have done some research I was just wondering if their was some hidden setting in the project settings or tool that allowed for a simpler way of testing system apps, I guess their isn't or if their is, it's not for the general public.